# Doctrine Annotation error in class with no Annotation

Tags: symfony, annotations, doctrine

I have just tried to make some changes to a Symfony2.1 application, mainly involving converting all my templates from php to twig, and adding some css styling.  The application works perfectly on my local host (xampp running on a windows7 machine).  However, when I moved all the changes over to my stage server (lampp stack on Ubuntu), I can't even get the login form to load.  When I check the apache error.log, I get the following...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\AnnotationException' 
with   message '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@ORM\\Table" in class MyBundle
\Controller\SecurityController was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" 
statement for this annotation?' in 
/opt/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:52
```

The thing is, my SecurityController class doesn't use Annotations, so I can't for the life of me see how this error is arising.

Here is the code for my SecurityController class:

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext; 

class SecurityController extends Controller {
  public function loginAction()
  {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    // get error if exists
    if($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
      $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    else  {
      $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
      $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username'=>$session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'=>$error
    ));
  }
}
```

I've searched on this error message, but it was mainly down to people forgetting the

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

or using

```
\Table
```

instead of

```
@ORM\Table
```

which I don't think is applicable in this case.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you use annotations? What do you use?

Comment: Your error sais `The annotation "@ORM\\Table" in class MyBundle
\Controller\SecurityController`, but you are showing us a `SecurityController` of another bundle: `CRUK\SampleTrackingBundle`. Is it correct?

Comment: @Dani Sancas - Sorry, I was trying to make my bundle more generic by calling it MyBundle (but forgot to change that everywhere). SecurityController is in the same bundle as stated in the error message.

Comment: @forgottenbas - yes I cleared the cache

Comment: @Gianni Alessandro - I use annotation for my Entity classes, but not in my controllers.  This is an application that has been in use for  a couple of years working fine, and I made what I thought were cosmetic changes, so I'm finding the error hard to track down.